# MYSQL : INSERT INTO COLUMN using data from other columns

Tags: mysql

I Have a mysql table TEST_TABLE2 Which looks something like :

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+
| thegroup | RSSI1 | RSSI2 | RSSI3 | RSSI4 | CLASS_LABELS |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+
| 1        |   100 |     0 |     2 |    33 | NULL         |
| 2        |   100 |   100 |     1 |     4 | NULL         |
| 3        |    96 |   100 |     1 |     1 | NULL         |
| 4        |    95 |   100 |     6 |     2 | NULL         |
| 5        |    98 |    98 |     5 |     1 | NULL         |
| 6        |    97 |   100 |     0 |     3 | NULL         |
| 7        |    44 |    97 |    14 |    15 | NULL         |
| 8        |     4 |    96 |    25 |    25 | NULL         |
| 9        |     0 |    99 |    28 |    29 | NULL         |
| 10       |     0 |   100 |    13 |    14 | NULL         |
```

Based on the values in columns RSSI1, RSSI2, RSSI3 and RSSI4 i want to fill the class_label columns based on some thresholds. For example if RSSI1 values in column 1 are less then 10 then put label 1 in class label. If values are between 10 and 90 put 2 else put 3. I want to run the same step for other columns RSSI2, RSSI3 AND RSSI4 as well. So for example the CLASS_LABELS column based on these thresholds should look like

```
3   1   1   2
3   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
2   3   2   2
1   3   2   2
1   3   2   2
1   3   1   1
```

how can i best achieve this? I also wanted to pass the thresholds 10 and 90 as arguments to a function in mysql which loops with respect to thegroup field from 1 to 10, so if i change these arguments for example 0 to 50, 51 to 90 and 90 to 100 new class labels will be generated. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One single update statement with a case construct should do it. You could consider a trigger to get this value current.

Comment: There is no reason to populate a column with a value evaluated from other columns. Poor database design and a waste of space and drag on other functions. If any of those columns are modified the value could then be inaccurate. But @VMai is right that CASE is the MYSQL tool: case... when v1 between... and v2... then 1
when ... etc. Good luck.